# A graph $G$ is $r$-factorable iff $G$ is $k$-regular and $k$ is a multiple of $r$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

An $r$-factor of a graph like $G$ is a spanning subgraph of $G$ which is $r$-regular.

A graph $G$ is called $r$-factorable if we can decompose edges of $G$ to $r-$factors.

Prove that :
A graph like $G$ is $r$-factorable iff  $G$ is $k$-regular and $k$ is a multiple of $r$.

Note : I draw some examples and i know that this is true but what i'm stuck on is how to write a formal proof for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you prove that if $\deg_Gv\ge r$ for each vertex $v$ of $G$, then $G$ has an $r$-factor?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can i prove that with philip hall's theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is not valid.  A classic example is the Petersen Graph, which is a 3-regular graph that is not 1-factorable, even though 3 is a multiple of 1. Other examples of regular graphs that are not 1-factorable include any regular graph with an odd number of nodes, e.g., an odd cycle or a complete graph with an odd number of nodes.